# Reading a HttpRequest post data on OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I am sending a HTTP request from a C# windowsform application to an OpenCart store.

This is what fiddler is showing that I'm sending, which looks correct.

[image]

This is the code I have in my OpenCart project that I'm calling.

```
class ControllerEAOpenCartProducts extends ControllerEAOpenCart {

   public function createProduct()
    {
        print_r($this->request);
    }
}
```

The print_r is outputting the following data which doesn't appear to be containing any of my JSON data.

The content type of the requst also seems to be incorrect, shouldn't it be application/json like the request in fiddler shows?

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Mar 2015 10:50:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=23dbd33ede35cbeb5486054d06a773a2; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: language=en; expires=Fri, 03-Apr-2015 10:50:33 GMT; path=/; domain=opencart.exact3ex.co.uk
Set-Cookie: currency=USD; expires=Fri, 03-Apr-2015 10:50:33 GMT; path=/; domain=opencart.exact3ex.co.uk
Set-Cookie: DYNSRV=lin170; path=/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1826

Request Object
(
    [get] => Array
        (
            [route] => EAOpenCart/Products/createProduct
        )

    [post] => Array
        (
        )

    [cookie] => Array
        (
        )

    [files] => Array
        (
        )

    [server] => Array
        (
            [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 200
            [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json
            [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/sites/o/opencart.exact3ex.co.uk/public_html
            [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
            [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
            [HTTP_EXPECT] => 100-continue
            [HTTP_HOST] => opencart.exact3ex.co.uk
            [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 194.143.179.2
            [PATH] => /bin
            [QUERY_STRING] => route=EAOpenCart/Products/createProduct
            [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
            [REMOTE_ADDR] => 194.143.179.2
            [REMOTE_PORT] => 60376
            [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
            [REQUEST_URI] => /?route=EAOpenCart/Products/createProduct
            [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/sites/o/opencart.exact3ex.co.uk/public_html/index.php
            [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
            [SERVER_ADDR] => 10.168.1.170
            [SERVER_ADMIN] => you@example.com
            [SERVER_NAME] => opencart.exact3ex.co.uk
            [SERVER_PORT] => 80
            [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
            [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
            [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
            [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
            [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1425466233.43
            [REQUEST_TIME] => 1425466233
            [argv] => Array
                (
                    [0] => route=EAOpenCart/Products/createProduct
                )

            [argc] => 1
            [HTTPS] => 
        )

    [request] => Array
        (
            [route] => EAOpenCart/Products/createProduct
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like opencart's request class wraps php's globals. These only get populated when regular form data is submitted.

To access json, you need to use the lower level input stream:

```
public function createProduct()
{
    print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));
}
```

Comment: @Eritey Look at the server property of the request object in your question, all header info should be in there. Another option if using apache server, you can use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: @Eritey Also, please mark this answer as correct when you get the chance

Comment: I had to wait for time to have passed before marking it as correct, I've marked it now :)  thank you again