# Invalid Request type Angular2

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, observable

Can you tell me where I'm wrong? When I use the Postman then it's working.But why I cannot do the same using Angular2? Here the backend api is from PHP.I have never used PHP backend before.Is that different than normal ASP.net Web Api? I mean the way we have to send the parameters and all...

**Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationData {
  authenticationEndPoint: string = "https://www.myk.com/admin/index.php?route=api/login";

  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

  //to login
  loginUser(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');

   /*let body = {
     username: username,
     password: password,
   }*/ Not working this too :(

    let body='username=myname&password=admin';//I tried hardcode value.But not working 

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.authenticationEndPoint, body, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

**login.ts**

```
//to login
  loginUser(): void {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.authenticationData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.response = data;
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        },
        () => console.log('Complete')
      );
    }
  }
```

**Error:**

> body: "{"error":"Invalid Request type","status":"201"}", status: 200,
>   ok: true, statusText: "OK",

**Php:**

```
<?php
class ControllerApiLogin extends Controller {
 private $error = array();

 public function index() {
  $json = array();

  if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && !empty($this->request->get['username']) && !empty($this->request->get['password'])) {

   if(!empty($this->request->get['username']) && !empty($this->request->get['password'])){

    $this->load->language('common/login');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    // User
    $this->registry->set('user', new Cart\User($this->registry));

    if ($this->validate()) {

     $token = token(32);

     $token_count = $this->user->getUniqueToken($token);

     if($token_count==0)
     {
      $this->session->data['token'] = $token; 
     }else{

      $token = token(32);

      $token_count = $this->user->getUniqueToken($token);

      $this->session->data['token'] = $token;  
     }

     $this->load->model('user/user');

     $user_info = $this->model_user_user->getUserByEmail($this->request->get['username']);

     $tokeninfo = array();

     if(count($user_info) > 0){

      $tokeninfo = array(
       'token' => $token,
       'user_id' => $user_info['user_id'],
       'ip'  => $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']
      );

      $date_expired = $this->model_user_user->addUserapitoken($tokeninfo);

     }else{
      $date_expired = '';
     }

     $json['token'] = $token;
     $json['date_expired'] = $date_expired;
     $json['status'] = '200';
    }else{
     $json['error'] = "No match for Username and/or Password.";
     $json['status'] = '201';
    }

   }else{
    $json['error'] = 'Something Went Wrong!!! <br> PLease Enter Correct Login Credentials!!!';
    $json['status'] = '201';
   }

   //$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
   //$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
  }
  else{

    $json['error'] = 'Invalid Request type';
    $json['status'] = '201';
  }
  if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
   $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $this->request->server['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
   $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
   $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
   $this->response->addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
  }

  $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
  $this->response->addHeader('HTTP/1.1'.$json['status']);
  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }

 protected function validate() {

  //$this->registry->set('user', new Cart\User($this->registry));

  if (!isset($this->request->get['username']) || !isset($this->request->get['password']) || !$this->user->login($this->request->get['username'], html_entity_decode($this->request->get['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))) {
   $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_login');
  }

  return !$this->error;
 }
}
```

Comment: are you receiving data as json?

Comment: yes, it is. @suraj

Comment: then check my answer..you are sending as a form string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's feedback:** I have to use it like this.Cheers :)

```
authenticationEndPoint: string = "https://www.myk.com/admin/index.php?route=api/login&username=";

loginUser(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    let body = '';
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let url = this.authenticationEndPoint + encodeURI(username) + '&password=' + encodeURI(password);

    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

**Original Answer:**

```
headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
let body='username=myname&password=admin';//I tried hardcode value.But not working
```

You seem to be setting content type as json. So your body needs to be set as an object. Do:

```
let body ={
  username:myname,
  password:admin
}
```

And then send the request. It should convert this to json and send.

```
 return this.http.post(this.authenticationEndPoint, body, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Actually, that was my first try.It didn't work.That's why I tried to do as hard code value.That too not working.This is PHP endpoint.Is that different? I never used PHP backend before.

Comment: no.. it wont be different..It depends on how your php code is receiving the request..can you put that part in the question?

Comment: you are getting form data in php..not json.. is this symfony?

Comment: I didn't get you? more explanation, please?

Comment: you have set contentType as "application/json" in request javascript..In your server side php you are doing `$this->request->get['password']`.. this is receiving POST request as key-value pair. i.e. form...and I asked if it is symfony framework

Comment: They mentioned `opencart`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852679/reading-a-httprequest-post-data-on-opencart

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to use [**`URLSearchParams`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) instead, and send the data as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON. The URLSearchParams will encode the parameters as you have tried when hardcoding, but I think your problem is when you are trying to send it as JSON, send it as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead. So try this:

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

loginUser(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set('username',username);
  body.set('password',password)

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.post(this.authenticationEndPoint, body.toString(), options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //you need to import this
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, Request, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';                
                 this.body= {
                  "username":myname,
                  "password":admin
                } //body is defined here
                let headers = new Headers();
                headers.append('HeaderKey', headerValue);


                let options = new RequestOptions({
                  method: RequestMethod.Post,
                  url: this.authenticationData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password),
                  body: this.body,
                  headers: headers
                });
                   //here you are making request 
                this.http.request(new Request(options))
                  .map(res => res.json())
                  .subscribe(data => {
                      //data is fetched
                   if(data.code==200){
                  this.response = data;
                          }
                       else{
                  console.log("some issue with the api response")}
        }, err => {
                    console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
                  });
```

May be this way things will work for you